# All included in the Stack Overflow data dump?

Tags: support, data-dump

If I download the January 2011 data dump then will I get all the data since the site started?

As I can see that the size of the data dump is increasing, and I can see in October there are some information for some other months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will get all the data from the time the sites started up to January 2011.